# MySQL split cell value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL code, which should (for each row) take the value of the column `Cislo` and then update the current row, setting the column `Cislo` and `Nazov` to `SUBSTRING`s of the current value.

So let's say currently
`Cislo = 12345LoremIpsum` and `Nazov=''`, after the update it should be `Cislo=12345` and `Nazov=LoremIpsum`.

I have tried many different approaches, however the results are always empty cells.

```
UPDATE `skladovekartyvyrobok00001` SET 
    `Cislo`= SUBSTRING(`Cislo`,0,5),
    `Nazov`= SUBSTRING(`Cislo`,5)
    WHERE `ID`=31;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) might start as `1` instead of `0`

> A negative value may be used for pos in any of the forms of this function. A value of 0 for pos returns an empty string.

Then you can use a little trick to update `Nazov` column first and then update `Cislo`

I think you might try this.

```
UPDATE `skladovekartyvyrobok00001` SET 
    `Nazov`= SUBSTRING(`Cislo`,6),
    `Cislo`= SUBSTRING(`Cislo`,1,5)
    WHERE `ID`=31;
```

[sqlifddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ea389c96211961229c28714a9c6385a1)

Comment: It produced the result for the `Cislo` field, but `Nazov` remained empty....

Comment: @Michal I had edited my answer, you can try that

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring says:

> A value of 0 for `pos` returns an empty string.

In other words, the substring position is 1-based, not 0-based.